# Running multiple commands in a single line of for /f

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run more than one command in for /f in the windows command line (or from a batch file).  Here's simplified code that exhibits the problem:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %a IN (`echo a & echo b`) do echo %a
```

This gives the error message:

```
& was unexpected at this time.
```

Each of the following works fine:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %a IN (`echo a`) do echo %a
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %a IN (`echo b`) do echo %a
echo a & echo b
```

So my question is whether or not it is possible to run two commands together the way I am trying to do in a single for /f loop.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `&` so it's parsed as part of the subexpression, and not as part of the FOR.  Change `&` to `^&`

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %a IN (`echo a ^& echo b`) do echo %a
```

As a side note, this line will work at the command line, but usually you intend to put it into a batch file.  In the batch file, you will need to double the percent signs as well by changing `%a` to `%%a`, like this:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (`echo a ^& echo b`) do echo %%a
```